# How to import my YouTube channel into WordPress?

Tags: plugins, customization, videos, youtube

I want to know how to import my YouTube channel into my WordPress website?

---

Example:

I have [a YouTube channel with 7 videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/CreswickCreative3205#g/c/0E4DB29E724360BE).  I want to bring all the videos into my WordPress website's sidebar. If I click the listed videos from my channel's list, it'll need to play.  For more reference this is the sample output that I need:

[image: screenshot of desired video layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the plugin [Tubepress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tubepress/). It has a lot of options to suit your needs, such as a sidebar widget that can play your videos in a lightbox for example. I used it a few times, it's quite powerfull and customizable.

Comment: I use Tubepress too, great plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try out the ["Yunero" jQuery plugin](http://www.codehandling.com/2013/02/yunero-jquery-plugin-displays-video.html) for Youtube feeds. Works for any channel upload/playlists.

Or even better, you can use the [Youmax WordPress plugin](http://www.codehandling.com/2015/02/youmax-40-for-wordpress-bring-youtube.html) for a full fledged YouTube Channel embed. This will show all your playlists and videos as thumbnails and has popup or inline players like you have in your screenshot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take another way, you can also use a [RSS approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752447/how-to-get-a-youtube-channel-rss-feed-after-2015-april-20-without-v3-api) or use the [official YouTube API](https://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/api-resources.html) for maximum control over the output.

I have used that once to build a video gallery, fetching video descriptions, views and more. Worked very well, but you should use some caching system like [the Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to cache data you gathered and won´t change fast/often like descriptions, thumbnails and more.